# Cannot debug Git version of project (Xamarin)

Tags: git, debugging, xamarin

I'm 100% new to Visual Studio and Xamarin.

I'm working on a project. When I work on the local version, I see these options in the toolbar, and I'm able to run and debug:

[image]

When I work on the Git version, I see these options in the toolbar, and I get the following error:

[image]

[image]

Reading other threads on SO, I think Visual Studio is trying to run my mobile app as a Win32 application. It looks like I need to change some settings, but I don't know how. Can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: what are the differences between the local and git versions - literally, what does "git diff" say has changed?

Comment: Hi Jason -- thanks for helping out. As far as I can tell, the local version is an exact copy of the Git version. I downloaded the ZIP file from Git, unzipped it, and loaded the solution locally. Since they're different solutions, I'm not able to use "Git diff" however.